# Rails reverse geocoder is returning nill result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

in model Location

```
reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :lng
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

in controller

```
@location = @employee.locations.find(params[:id])
@add = @location.address
```

it gives me  "Reserved" as a result. also i have address column in my location table to...can you tell me right way of getting address from coordinates

Comment: my problem solve thanks...i just receive my update location and my address column automatically populate with address.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
geocoded_by :address
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode
```

Comment: Given a Place model with known latitude/longitude coordinates, automatically fetch address and store in location attribute (stored in address attribute if :address option omitted) its mean that your answer only works when there is a location column in my table ..i have address column in my table so if i delete this line {:address => :location} my location store in my address column

Comment: then you do it for address only. What about using forward and reverse geocoding on model?